# How to skip one of the dependency file to not include while creating target library

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I want to create a library skipping one of the dependency file not to include while creating the same.

Eg:-

```
liba.so: a.o b.o c.o test.psm
        <command for creating liba.so, which includes all its dependencies.>
```

Here when there is a change is any of its dependencies i have to create `liba.so` file. But `.so` file should include only .o files and not `test.psm` file.

It will throw the error when we try to create .so file with non-object file.

Please help me how can we achieve this using GNUmake.

Comment: There are several ways it could be done, but first, you should answer a preliminary question for yourself: if `test.psm` is not meant to go into the library, then why is it a prerequisite for the library?  Because the best and most idiomatic approach would probably be to sidestep the question by removing `test.psm` from the prerequisite list.

Comment: test.psm file is a form of xml format where we will update known errors and warnings. Every time if we add any new content in that file we want to build the library.

Comment: Rebuilding the library from its constituent object files is pointless if the objects have not changed.  Rebuilding the objects from their sources is pointless if neither the sources nor the compilation options have changed.  On the other hand, given a makefile that correctly represents all targets' true prerequisites and provides appropriate build recipes, `make` will automatically rebuild everything that needs to be built in response to any changes.  So I'm still not seeing any good reason for `test.psm` to be a prerequisite of `liba.so`.

Comment: Okay, But still i want to know how to achieve skipping one of the pre-requisite while building .so.

Comment: Which is "the error"? I can't see what would go wrong. To create a dynamic list of dependecies, simply use a variable `liba.so: $(LIBA_DEPS)` although this will make your makefile more complicated to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best way to solve the problem is to *avoid* it.**  I see absolutely no reason to rebuild a library that exists already and whose prerequisites have not changed since it was last built. If for some bizarre reason one wants to ensure that the library's timestamp is not earlier than that of some associated documentation file, then the best alternatives would run along the lines of creating a separate process around maintaining or distributing that file. For example,

- `touch` a corresponding source file whenever the documentation file is changed; or
- build the documentation *from* the corresponding source, such as via a Doxygen or a similar tool, so that it is a built artifact that shares the same prerequisites as the library; or
- manage timestamps as part of the installation / distribution process instead of the build process.  For instance, make a copy, without timestamp preservation, before installing or distributing the built files, so that all the files in the copy are timestamped as of the copying.

**But** if you must obey the dictates of a pointy-haired boss who will not accept pushback, then the answer to the actual question is that `make` does not have any special variable or operator for designating subsets of rules' prerequisite lists, but you nevertheless have plenty of options for writing the recipe appropriately.  This then becomes about the details of of the rule's recipe.

If one starts with

```
liba.so: a.o b.o c.o
        $(archiver_command) $(archiver_options) a.o b.o c.o
```

then one can add `test.psm` to the prerequisite list without any other changes.

Suppose one starts with a rule of this form, however:

```
liba.so: a.o b.o c.o
        $(archiver_command) $(archiver_options) $^
```

.  The recipe uses the automatic variable `$^` to refer to the (whole) list of prerequisites, so if one adds `test.psm` as a new prerequisite then it would be included, too, which you do not want.  You have multiple options here, among them

- Use shell code in the recipe to process the prerequisite list and remove the last element.  This is a bit nasty.
- Rewrite the recipe in the previous form, with an explicit list of objects in the recipe instead of a variable.  This carries an added maintenance burden, however.
- Designate the *real* prerequisites via a user-defined variable, and use that in the recipe, too.  This may be particularly natural in view of the fact that it is common for there already to be just such a variable.

The last alternative would be my recommendation.  Specifically, it would look something like this:

```
A_OBJS = a.o b.o c.o

# ...

liba.so: $(A_OBJS) test.psm
        $(archiver_command) $(archiver_options) $(A_OBJS)
```